# Проблема с чтением кода

Tags: java

День добрый, учу джаву почти 2мес., допустим вижу циклы/методы в коде понимаю, что они делают, но собрать воедино картину в голове не получается, всё рушится. Вот сейчас сижу смотрю на простую задачку уже почти 2часа, вроде всё понятно и легко, но в голове не укладывается, что будет в итоге. Вопрос таков, где и как лучше всего потренировать навык чтения кода? Спасибо.

Comment: На всяких экзаменах полно вопросов типа "что напечатает этот фрагмент кода" или "Откомпилируется ли вот это, и если нет, то почему". Погуглите Java mock exam и попробуйте порешать задачи на каком-нибудь из них. А общий подход ссотоит в том, чтобы представить себя Java-машиной и мысленно выполнять инструкции одну за другой, можно получающиеся значения переменных на бумажку при этом записывать.

Answer (score 0):

Это приходит с опытом, некоторые советуют работу над open-source проектами, но когда я начинал, мне это не подходило, т.к. тогда опен сорс проекты казались мне слишком сложными.

В свое время просто начал писать свою небольшую игру по книге и все. Когда даже свой проект становится достаточно большим, ты не будешь помнить все его части и работая над ним ты постоянно будешь возвращаться к каким-то компонентам, снова и снова в них разбираться. Так и будет тренироваться этот навык.

То есть мой совет - не решать мелкие задачи, а попробовать поработать над каким-то своим чуть более крупным проектом, чем просто какая-то задачка вроде сортировки строк. И со временем этот навык придет естественным путем без каких-то особых упражнений для его тренировки.

P.S. Единственный момент, если пойдете этим путем, старайтесь делать свой проект, основываясь на чужом примере, например, по книге/видеокурсу или еще чему-то. Можно легко подхватить плохие привычки, которые надо будет потом искоренять.

Comment: Не знаю, я бы не очень советовал писать своё, не читая чужого, по принципу "я Пушкина  не читал, я писатель, а не читатель". От этого могут выработаться дурные привычки в отношении стиля и идиом, от которых потом очень трудно избавиться.

Comment: @m.vokhm да, хороший совет, я дополню ответ! Сам тоже по книге  mastering libgdx game development шел и просто делал свой проект, копируя принципы. Да, действительно без примера сложно будет что-то построить адекватное. Просто с опенсорса сложно без объяснений понять, почему это сделано так, а не эдак, если никто не подскажет.

Answer (score 0):

Практика. Только практика. Но если не можешь связать всё воедино, начни с изучения блок-схем. Станет нагляднее